# Convert Python dictionary to JSON with a specific format

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I am using python to parse an excel spreadsheet using columns of the data to create a hierarchical tree structure.  I have successfully parsed it into a python dictionary that I can json dump into the following format:

```
{
  "1": {
    "1a": [
      "Apple",
      "Orange"
    ],
    "1b": [
      "Horse"
    ]
  },
  "2": {
    "2b": [
      "Spinach",
      "Nut"
    ]
  }
}
```

But I need to convert it to this final json output format:

```
[
    {
      "name":"1",
      "children": [
        {
          "name":"1a",
          "children":
          [
            {"name":"Apple"},
            {"name":"Orange"}
          ]
        },
        {
          "name":"1b",
          "children": [
            {"name":"Horse"}
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name":"2",
      "children": [
        {
          "name":"2b",
          "children": [
            {"name":"Spinach"},
            {"name":"Nut"}
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
]
```

Is there a way to either manipulate the python dictionary or to change the json to achieve this?
I am new to python and I feel like there's something I am definitely missing here.

Comment: Your json output format is not valid json.  Maybe missing ']' ?

Answer (score 2):

Your output JSON isn't quite correct, but this shows how to generate something similar (it was missing a couple of list/array brackets):

```
src = {
    "1": {
        "1a": [
        "Apple",
        "Orange"
        ],
        "1b": [
        "Horse"
        ]
    },
    "2": {
        "2b": [
        "Spinach",
        "Nut"
        ]
    }
}

dst =   [{
        "name":"1",
        "children": [
        {
            "name":"1a",
            "children":
            [
            {"name":"Apple"},
            {"name":"Orange"}
            ]
        },
        {
            "name":"1b",
            "children": [
            {"name":"Horse"}
            ]
        }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name":"2",
        "children": [
        {
            "name":"2b",
            "children": [
            {"name":"Spinach"},
            {"name":"Nut"}
            ]
        }
        ]
    }
]

def fixup(what):
    if isinstance(what, str):
        return dict(name=what)
    elif isinstance(what, list):
        return [fixup(x) for x in what]
    else:
        assert isinstance(what, dict)
        return [dict(name=x, children=fixup(y)) for x, y in sorted(what.items())]

assert fixup(src) == dst
```

Answer (score 1):

it is about reformatting your data not about json it self ,

here what I came up with,it's a bit confusing

```
import json
x = {"1": {"1a": ["Apple", "Orange"], "1b": ["Horse"]}, "2": {"2b": ["Spinach", "Nut"]}}
def conv(k, v):
    return {"name": k, "children": list({"name": x, "children": list({"name": z}  for z in v[x])} for x in v)}
print json.dumps(list(conv(k, x[k]) for k in x), indent=4)
```

I hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

The JSON output shown in your question is missing some bracket characters. Regardless, I think what you should do is reformat the hierarchical tree structure you have into the structure you need to json dump:

```
import json

tree = {
  "1": {
    "1a": [
      "Apple",
      "Orange"
    ],
    "1b": [
      "Horse"
    ]
  },
  "2": {
    "2b": [
      "Spinach",
      "Nut"
    ]
  }
}

objects = [
    {'name': branch,
     'children': [
        {'name': subbranch,
         'children': [{'name': subchild} for subchild in subchildren]
        } for subbranch, subchildren in children.items()
     ]
    } for branch, children in tree.items()
]

print(json.dumps(objects, indent=2))
```